# Complete the last Tread C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, task

I'm doing the application and I have a problem with the user interface. The user calls up an asynchronous method, which receives the description text. If the user calls the method 10 times, the label in which the description text is displayed is flashed 10 times. It is necessary for me that from 10 times caused method only last showed result, how to me to cancel the previous Tasks (threads)?

```
private async void DisplayShortDescription(object parameter)
{
    var id = (int) parameter; // as string;         
    var description = await FindDescription(id);

    ShortDescription = description.ShortDescription;
    CurrentDescriptionId = id;
}
```

Only last task should execute these lines:

```
ShortDescription = description.ShortDescription;
CurrentDescriptionId = id;
```

Comment: ideally you shouldn't start the new thread if the old is running unless the new thread is likely to have a different result

Comment: You can always check if the task is already running before you call it again. Post also how you execute the task.

Comment: The user clicks on the buttons, and the text of the description is requested from the server. If the user presses the buttons quickly, the label in which the description is displayed will flash. It is necessary to check that this is the last thread and only then perform the last 2 lines

Comment: Can I somehow get the last Task, and then check that it is valid last?

Comment: @NikitaGoncharyk - Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Maybe you should disable the button the user pressed until the task has finished execution (so that the user cannot press it multiple times)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit: if you really want to check if it is the last thread**

If you want to check, then store the task object:

```
private Task<?> _lastTask;
private async void DisplayShortDescription(object parameter)
{
    var id = (int) parameter; // as string;   
    var currentTask = FindDescription(id)
    _lastTask = currentTask;      
    var description = await currentTask;

    if (currentTask == _lastTask)
    {
        ShortDescription = description.ShortDescription;
        CurrentDescriptionId = id;
    }
}
```

---

What you really want to do is check if the properties have changed:

```
    private async void DisplayShortDescription(object parameter)
    {
        var id = (int) parameter; // as string;         
        var description = await FindDescription(id);

        if (ShortDescription != description.ShortDescription)
        {
            ShortDescription = description.ShortDescription;
        }
        if (CurrentDescriptionId != id)
        {
            CurrentDescriptionId = id;
        }
    }
```

Better still, you can handle this in your property:

```
private string _shortDescription;
public property string ShortDescription
{
    get { return _shortDescription; }
    set 
    {
        if (_shortDescription == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _shortDescription = value;
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the last Task, and then check that it is valid last?

Comment: @NikitaGoncharyk check my edit at the top of my answer.

Comment: Also: it might be possible you want to make your _lastTask static in this case (depends on your code)

Comment: each user click gives a different text description, so checking for compliance does not give anything

Comment: Thank you it works. But I do not know whether it is possible to do better in my case, I would really like to know

Comment: main problem with this is that if the user clicks 10 times you have 9 threads running that you don't care about and never will, as this doesn't cancel them they will still run even though you don't need them any more

Comment: @Enigmativity this works precisely because it's not thread safe, if the _lasttask is changed by another thread then it doesn't execute the update, you can use a lock statement if you need to ensure thread safety for a code block

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is store the task

so where you have `var description = await FindDescription(id);`

you can do

```
task = FindDescription(id);
var description  = await task;
```

where task is

```
private Task<FindDescriptionReturnType> task;
```

then you can do something like

```
public void Button_Click(){
    if(task?.IsCompleted??true)
    {
        DisplayShortDescription()
    }
}
```

however if you do need to cancel the operation the .net way is to use
[CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = CancellantionMethod(source.Token);
source.Cancel();
await task;

public async Task CancellantionMethod(CancellationToken token) {
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

most async methods that support cancellation will accept a cancellation token as a parameter

if you can't cancel safely like in the loop above CancellationToken also provides a method`ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` which will terminate your code with an exception

Comment: Thanks, i will also try your method.